# Eclipse: Can you split a project-specific plugin properties file?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin, preferences

My Eclipse plugin stores project-specific preferences in `org.myplugin.ide.eclipse.core.prefs`, which contains multiple preferences as key-value-pairs. I want to put some of these preferences under version control and ignore others. To do this, I would have to split the file into two files. Is that possible? In case it is: how?

FYI: The plugin is the Sonar Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: Are you the plugin author or a plugin user?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- not version the `org.myplugin.ide.eclipse.core.prefs` file at all
- version only the values you are interested in in a separate "value file"
- version a script able to modify the `org.myplugin.ide.eclipse.core.prefs` file it founds, changing the right lines with the data from the versioned "value file".
  That would restore the `org.myplugin.ide.eclipse.core.prefs` file with the value you expect to see (and which are versioned in said "value file")

You can do that automatically in git with a [content filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767854/track-local-ignored-files-with-git/14768125#14768125) declared in a `.gitattributes` file:

[image: content filter]

On checkout, the script registered in that .gitattributes will look for a `org.myplugin.ide.eclipse.core.prefs` file and perform the necessary value adjustments.